Where are the app-specific keychain entries stored in Mac OS?
I have a Catalyst app that stores a password in the keychain like this:
    NSDictionary *keychainItem = @{
                                   (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                   (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier],
                                   (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier],
                                   (__bridge id)kSecValueData: [pass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                   };
    
    if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainItem, NULL) == noErr)
    {
        [SMIKeychainHelper updateKeychainItemWithPass:(NSString *)pass];
    }
    else
    {
        OSStatus sts = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainItem, NULL);
        NSLog(@"Error Code: %d", (int)sts);
    }

And it works, and it's available when needed. But why can't I see it in the Keychain Access app? I also tried using the security command line-tool, but no luck either. Is MacOS hiding those app specific keychains somehow? I would really like to understand how this works.

How are you searching for the keychain item with security?

@l'L'l security find-generic-password -a <bundle id> -s <bundle id> -w but even list-keychains gives me the 3 default ones, which i checked with Keychain Access.. I suspect there could be hidden keychains for each app?

I tried your code and I could see the keychain item without issue; maybe try security find-generic-password -a "AppName" (without the extension), is there any difference?

No luck yet, I also tried on another mac, since this is a managed machine and I thought perhaps that fact accounts for it. I will try to print out as much information about the keychain from within the app next and see if I can make sense of it.

I should add, it's a sandboxed app that uses app groups. But writing code that attempts to read the keychain while not being the same app, fails. Will now research how sandboxing works..
